# SIM7600 HTTP post 204

Tags: arduino, stm32, embedded, modem

Using stm32L451 with a Sim7600.

I am trying to post data to a Ubitdots dashboard using HTTP post and the response is 204 which means no data is load but a connection was made to the server, I have managed to post data using this method using the sim800.

This is my method:

AT+CREG?
AT+CGREG?
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://xxxxx"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPDATA=284,4000

***I send the following data once download appears****
{"Battery" : 10,"Signal" : 45,"HR" : 0, "Panic": 0,"GPS" : {"value": 1,"context":{"lat":-34.0004802,"lng":22.4305863}},"Unit" : {"value": 1,"context":{"value":"Taking asda"}},"Next-Location" : {"value": 1,"context":{"value":"B4"}},"Guard" : {"value": 1,"context":{"value":"Tasdsad"}}

AT+HTTPACTION=1

And from here I am receiving the 204 error. It seems that the sim7600 module is not acknowledging the data I send through.

What am I missing?

Comment: 204 is not an error code; it means that the server has successfully fulfilled your request, but has nothing to send in response. It is basically (and very loosely) an ACK without further comment.

Comment: but then why on postman do I get a response back and on the ubidots dashboard the values do not update?

Comment: What happens when you send the same request from your computer?